# I entered such as "0.5 , 0.8 " but it give error. how to fix in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Store_20190808001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tara = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("      Story Inventory Enter    ");
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Ayran we have : " );        
        int ayransayisi = tara.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the cost of Ayran  : " );
        long ayranparasi = tara.nextLong();
        System.out.println("thanks");
        float kar = (ayranparasi* ayransayisi );
        System.out.println("kar " + kar);
    }
}
```

I entered floats such as " 0.5 , 3.5 " but it give error How ı fix this

Comment: `long ayranparasi = tara.nextLong();` you are telling Java to get `Long` data type from the user but then you enter .3 which is not a long type.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Thanks how can ı do ? How can ı use kind of data type

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

From the Java docs

> nextDouble()- Scans the next token of the input as a double.
>
> nextFloat()- Scans the next token of the input as a float.
>
> nextInt() - Scans the next token of the input as an int.

As you are giving input as 0.5 and 0.8 you need to scan the input either using nextDouble() or nextFloat()

Below is the working example -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tara = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("      Story Inventory Enter    ");
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Ayran we have : " );        
        double ayransayisi = tara.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the cost of Ayran  : " );
        double ayranparasi = tara.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("thanks");
        double kar = (ayranparasi* ayransayisi );
        System.out.println("kar " + kar);
    }
}
```

Output -

```
Story Inventory Enter    
Enter the number of Ayran we have : 0.5
Enter the cost of Ayran  : 3.5
thanks
kar 1.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `float ayranparasi = tara.nextFloat()` and you must also note that you must enter your numbers in the correct format, that is, you can't type something like 3. 3 or s9 but rather 3.3 and 9, because an exception will be thrown. For more info and examples on the Scanner class you can visit https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp